# What is a way to get the object Array from the object Vector in Julia?

Tags: julia

There is `maintype(t) = getfield(parentmodule(t), nameof(t))`, but it's rather indirect...

Does anyone know a better way?

[original post](https://julialang.slack.com/archives/C6A044SQH/p1568622590092100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `Base.typename(t).wrapper` given `t` is the same `t` you referenced in your question!

[original post](https://julialang.slack.com/archives/C6A044SQH/p1568622590092100)

Comment: I wouldn't call this a very good solution -- it is reaching for internal fields like `.wrapper`.

Comment: I'm open to a better solution! feel free to post it if you get a chance.